# Accessing page content when using deeply nested React Navigation navigators on iOS Using Appium

Tags: ios, react-native, automation, appium, react-native-navigation

Does anyone have any experience with React Navigation 5 on iOS and nested navigators?

It appears that in appium once the navigation tree hits 5 nested navigators on iOS that instead of being able to access the current pages content it returns a single XCUIElementTypeOther element.

For instance if the navigation tree looks like
Stack -> Tab -> Stack -> Tab then the content tree is rendered correctly

But if there’s an extra level such as
Stack -> Tab -> Drawer -> Stack -> Tab then the content tree becomes that single XCUIElementTypeOther element

I had initial thought this could be down to not using the accessible prop correctly on the view containing the content (as this can cause similar behaviour) but after testing out a number of different nested navigation configurations and setting this prop on every view I believe it’s due to this.

I don’t have this issue on Android as the same structure works perfectly fine, is there just some config I’m missing?